# C# DNS Server redirection

Tags: c#, redirect, dns

I am trying to make my own dns server from scratch which will filter out domains with adult content and redirect user to web page with info that url they are trying to load contains adult content and that is is blocked.

So far so good, I have setup my own http server and I am replacing Ip addresses of blacklisted domain with my own server to display error (Not sure if this is right way to do it, and does other dna servers do it the same way).

Problem occures when I try to blacklist domain with https setup in which case after redirection browser displays error about untrusted source or something similar.

Is there a way to bypass this situation, or maybe to display my web page some other way?

**SOLUTION:**

It turned out it cannot be done with DNS as I planned, because I couldn't find out which domain is client tying to access so I could create fake certificate. After that I switched to proxy server instead of DNS server.

When client tries to connect to proxy server (for my solution I used TcpListener) first request will be CONNECT and it wont be encrypted so I could read domain from "Host" header and decide if domain should be blocked.

If blocked create fake certificate, open ssl connection (here is an example how to establish Ssl connection) and return block page as response, else with TcpClient make connection to real server and tunnel data both ways (Do not make SslStream, read and write directly to NetworkStream)

```
using(SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(context.ClientNetworkStream))
{
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(fakeCert);

    sslStream.Write(blockPageData, 0, blockPageData.Length);
}
```

Also, how to create fake certificate:

```
public void CreateCertificate(string domain, string path, X509Certificate2 rootCert, string certPassword)
{
    string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
    }

    SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
    sanBuilder.AddDnsName(domain);

    X500DistinguishedName distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN={domain}");

    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        CertificateRequest request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));


        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

        //Generates a cert, but does not provide a private key.
        using (X509Certificate2 certificate = request.Create(rootCert, new DateTimeOffset(rootCert.NotBefore), new DateTimeOffset(rootCert.NotAfter), new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }))
        {
            X509Certificate2 certWithPrivateKey = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);

            byte[] certBuffer = certWithPrivateKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, certPassword);

            using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
            {
                stream.Write(certBuffer, 0, certBuffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CaiusJard Or perhaps DNS over HTTPS :) Probably not though...

Comment: @John everything over HTTP! The whole internet's as one big workaround for a sysadmin who wont relax the firewall :)

Comment: My vote, for reasons given in my answer, is you leave it as is and let the users who want to watch the porn click "continue anyway" - it's a lot of work to get past an error message that is fairly inconsequential in the grand scheme of things. No one is going to land on your refusal page and go "gee, durn. Can't watch mah porn but at least I didn't have to click through a security warning to NOT get to watch it" and some users will be put off at the error page stage rather than getting put off at the "server says no" stage so.. same end result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to struggle with this one because the premise has a basic flaw:

- your user has typed https://prawnsite.com into their browser
- your DNS server has recognized it as an adult site and returned an Ip of 10.0.0.1 instead of the real 12.34.56.78
- the browser has connected to 10.0.0.1 and is trying to do certificate exchange and get an ask cert that identifies the server truly as prawnsite.com, before it does anything else
- your server doesn't have a certificate for that domain (but it could have if you obtained one)

There wouldn't me much worth in ssl certificates if any hacker could lash up a site that looks like your bank, infiltrate dns and redirect it so all the people on a particular ISP will be pointed to the fake site instead, and harvest their details. Which is basically what you're trying to do without the harvesting part. One of the major ideas of SSL as security is that the end user can be sure their computer really is talking to the server they want to be talking to, it's not just about encrypting the data so that people along the way (interim routers) can't grab it and inspect it

I mentioned that you could obtain a certificate for every site in your list; you may be able to find a service that issues basic ssl certificates intended for encrypting traffic but not validating server owner identity, on the fly. Have a google for "ssl on the fly" and see if anyone does it. Basic certs might well work for you, if for example the user isn't expecting (or doesn't care about) Extended Validation / green address bar. With an EV cert the issuer makes of sure the identity they are issuing for, but for a basic cert you just end up with a cert that bears the domain name being secured and once installed on your server the cert exchange will work out and the user's browser won't show any error

---

All that said, I think it might also be possible for you to install your custom web server on every user's machine, and code it up so that it creates and issues its own certificates based on its own trusted root certificate that has also been installed, and then send your porn site users to localhost.. like you would with a development certificate

Take a look at how Fiddler web debugging proxy does man-in-the-middle so you can inspect web traffic with it when the connection between the browser and the server is HTTPS (actually the browser connects to Fiddler and then Fiddler connects to server so it's two connections). Running your http server as a proxy server could also work out for what you need

Comment: Well, googling for "ssl on the fly" really helped. After some time I found a solution. My first try was by using HttpListener which wouldn't work in this in this setup.

All I needed to do is to start from TcpListener, create fake certificate and call AuthenticateAsServer on SslStream.

Comment: This guy could require everyone on his network to install his own self signed CA certs. That's how some enterprise products get around this. See this link for an example of a product that does this: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227987007-Block-Page-Errors-Installing-the-Cisco-Root-CA

Comment: Also an option I didn't consider- I kinda got the impression he wouldn't have that much control over the client computers but it's worth leaving the comment to stand as a supplement to the answer

Comment: @zmaster you can maybe even form up an answer of what code you used and what steps and post it up in response to your own question - it might be of use to future users ?